# Regular expression to extract any characters proceded by the futures' code?

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following character vector **code**

```
code <- c("M1808-C-2600", "AU2007C408", "TA109P3750")
```

And, I just want to extract all the characters behind the first or second letters, say, I need 1808-C-2600 from "M1808-C-2600", and 2007C408 from "AU2007C408".

My code is

```
code_after <- str_extract(code, pattern = "(?<=[:alpha:]+).*")
```

but it's wrong.
The error information is below, can anybody explain the error, the how to solve this?

```
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT, context=`(?<=[:alpha:]+).*`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all the letters at the beginning of the string using `sub` in base R.

```
code_after <- sub('^[A-Za-z]+', '', code)
code_after
#[1] "1808-C-2600" "2007C408"    "109P3750"
```

Comment: Sometime, the letters would be lower-case.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove all the letters at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Or with the character class `'^[[:alpha:]]+'`.